# betareg failing due to too many elements

Tags: r

I'm not sure if this question belongs to stack overflow or cross validate, but ill ask for help any way.

I'm  trying to use a model for explaining variable which is a proportion,that's why i used `betareg`
as following:

```
 br <- betareg(ctr ~as.factor(change_point) , data = subset(ctr_drop,ctr>0 & ctr<1))
> summary(br)
Error in diag(x %*% xwx1 %*% t(x)) : 
  allocMatrix: too many elements specified
>
```

Although the data might be big for that ( ~2 M records), i don't see why it doesn't work , i only inserted a single binary explaining variable, and as far as i know the model uses `MLE` , which works fine in other functions like `glm`.

```
 table(ctr_drop$change_point)

  after  before 
1329991  955998 
>
```

---

This question was answered in the comets, thanks

Comment: What is failing `betareg` or `summary`?

Comment: It seems that the call to `betareg` works as desired. The problem is in the `betareg:::summary.betareg` or more precisely in `betareg:::residuals.betareg`. So unless you need the residuals, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: thanks, , ill do that (the mean is showing), @shadow post it as answer, ill give you some credit